# x509: cannot validate certificate because it doesn't contain any IP SANs

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat, metricbeat

I'm trying to implement an ELK stack while gathering information with Filebeat and MetricBeat on clients.

Installation went well, filebeat is runing OK on the client and sending information to logstash (thanks to 'insecure: true).

Metricbeats don't want to connect at all and show:

`2017-02-08T15:57:36+01:00 ERR Connecting error publishing events (retrying): x509: cannot validate certificate for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx because it doesn't contain any IP SANs
2017-02-08T15:57:37+01:00 ERR Connecting error publishing events (retrying): x509: cannot validate certificate for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  because it doesn't contain any IP SANs`

I looked around and tried:

1.using FQDN for creating the ssl certs:

```
sudo openssl req -subj '/CN=ec2xxxxeu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/' -x509 -days 3650 -batch -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout private/logstash-forwarder.key -out certs/logstash-forwarder.crt
```

This shows :

```
2017-02-08T15:47:22+01:00 ERR Connecting error publishing events (retrying): x509: certificate is valid for , not ec2-34-249-172-152.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

2.using ip certs by putting 'subjectAltName = IP: ELK_server_private_IP' in openssl configuration then using:

```
sudo openssl req -config /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf -x509 -days 3650 -batch -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout private/logstash-forwarder.key -out certs/logstash-forwarder.crt
```

I followed this tutorial for ELK / filebeat installation 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana-elk-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04

That show the error msg in the title about SAN ips.

Do someone have an explanation of what's going on, do metrisbeats have a insecure:true to make it work?

Comment: what's your configuration file looks like? are you using FQDN or IP?